# How do I reload a UITableView's data when I don't know how many sections there will be?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

I'm a bit confused on how I can reload the cells in a `UITableView` after it's data has been changed. In particular, the confusion I'm having is that the new data could have more or less sections than what is currently on display. I know there's the `reloadSections:withRowAnimation:` method, but that requires a 1:1 replacement, where I may or may not have that.

I just want to tell the `UITableView` to scrap everything and reload as if for the first time. I'd appreciate someone shedding some light on this.

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE**

Here's the code I'm using which I've found the issue to be the cells not dequeueing after `reloadData` is called...

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];

    NSLog(@"%@", cell);

    if (cell == nil) {
        NSLog(@"%d; %d", indexPath.section, vehicle.inventoryCategoriesCount);

        if (indexPath.section < vehicle.inventoryCategoriesCount) {
            NSLog(@"Grouped cell");

            cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"] autorelease];

            NSString *model = [[[vehicle.inventory filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"category == %@", [vehicle.inventoryCategories objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]]] valueForKeyPath:@"@distinctUnionOfObjects.model"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

            cell.textLabel.text = model;
            cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [[vehicle.inventory filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"model == %@", model]] count]];
            cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Remove cell");

            cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"] autorelease];

            cell.textLabel.text = @"Remove an Item";
            cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
        }
    }

    NSLog(@"Adding a cell");

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `reloadData` on the table view.

```
[myTableView reloadData];
```

The documentation is here:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Hmmm, see I am calling that method after I get the data and parse it and update the arrays, but it's not changing the cells. I have an `MSMutableArray` that populates the table and the objects have a property called `category` and `model`. The `category` is the section, and the `model` is used to group the objects and display the count of each/model. Right now, I'm making the "add" code and it should be working, except that the model group it's changing is not updating its count... Kinda frustrating...

Comment: Actually, upon further testing, I see that when `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` is called, it's not dequeueing the cells from the previous creation. So, am I doing something wrong?

Comment: When you call `reloadData` it will call all your data source methods (numberOfSections, cellForRowAtIndexPath, etc.) again, so you must return the correctly updated values from there, and yes you should dequeue the reusable cells again here.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to say, the method is not dequeueing the previously made cells for some reason, and I'm not sure how to force it to do so...

Comment: Reading through other people's issues with the cells not refreshing, the answers say that it's an issue with the cell identifier. I tried messing with it, but it's not having an effect. I'm gonna update my answer with the actual code I have right now.

Comment: Giving you the points because in the context of my question you're technically right. However, I'm still having issues with how the cells are added in...

Answer (score 0):

If you are using core data and the fetched results controller, it's very straightforward. In fact, I believe you can see this if you build a sample core data project with a table view in it.

Two different methods come to mind:
controller didChangeSection is probably what you're looking for. The first is part of the fetchedresultscontroller delegate protocol. The second is part of the tableviewdatasource protocol.

```
- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeSection:(id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo>)sectionInfo
       atIndex:(NSUInteger)sectionIndex forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type {

     switch(type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
        [self.noteTableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        break;

    case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
        [self.noteTableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        break;
}
```

}

the other is:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
return [[fetchedResultsController sections] count];
```

}